# Unable to set environmental constant variables in Angular-2

Tags: angular

**I have done with**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  serviceURL: 'url'
}; --> in environments/environment.ts

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
serviceURL: environment.serviceURL;  --> in app.component.ts
```

But I am getting an error

***src/app/app.component.ts (17,22): Cannot find namespace 'environment'***

[My Project structure is attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcXQt.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
serviceURL = environment.serviceURL;
```

(`=` instead of `:`)

Comment: I had the same issue :) very confusing.